# ECS CLI - Mount EFS when launching container instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am using the [ecs-cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_CLI_tutorial.html) with a docker compose file and parameters defining my keypair, VPC, subnet, security groups, AMI etc...

However, the containers that run on the instance will need access to my EFS. So when ECS has a launched a new container instance, I want it to mount the EFS at a specific path on the instance/host even before starting the containers. I don't see a way of achieving this, is anyone aware of how to get this behavior?

Comment: Just to make sure I have what you're looking for correctly... you want the ECS service to mount an EFS drive as well? I don't think that's possible. Is there some reason you can't use a script in user-data when your ECS host launches to mount the EFS drive? If your paths are dynamic, you could also use user-data to deploy some sort of app that mounts EFS for you when needed.

Comment: Is it even possible to use the user-data script with the ecs-cli? if so, then that will solve the problem

Comment: You wouldn't use it at the ECS level, you'd use it when you launched your instance host EC2. I think the ecs-cli only interacts with the ECS service, not the underlying instance host, which it sounds like is where you need to map your EFS drive.

Comment: Oh, got it. The reason I was trying with ECS-CLI is because I wanted the cluster to autoscale and when new instances are added, the EFS is automatically mounted on them

Comment: I would solve this by running a user-data script that does something like this:

mkdir efs/
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1 <your EFS IP>:/ efs/

as part of an AMI that you would use to autoscale or in your CloudFormation script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I've ended up doing is:

- Create a Launch Configuration: When creating, in the Advanced section, set the user-data to mount the EFS (based on the example in this [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mount-fs-auto-mount-onreboot.html#mount-fs-auto-mount-on-creation)). **NOTE**: Make sure you give the IAM role for the instances in the launch configuration to be able to access EFS i.e. `AmazonElasticFileSystemFullAccess` or `AmazonElasticFileSystemReadOnlyAccess`
- Create an auto-scaling group and associate it with the above created launch configuration.
- Use the above created auto-scaling group with the Elastic Beanstalk application